# Reverse Geocoding in Google Maps api 3

Tags: javascript, google-maps-api-3, reverse-geocoding

I Have Following Javascript Code And I want to Apply Reverse Geocoding For My map

Here is My JS Code

**Update**

```
 <script  type="text/javascript">
 var map;
 var geocoder;
 var markers = new Array();    
 function initialize() {
 geocoder = new google.maps.Geocoder(); 
 var GPS = <%=GPS %>
     var latlng = new google.maps.LatLng(31.2330555556,72.3330555556);
     var myOptions = {
      zoom: 7,
      scaleControl:true,
      pancontrol: true,
      streetViewControl: true,
      center: latlng,
      mapTypeControl: true,
      mapTypeControlOptions: {
      style: google.maps.MapTypeControlStyle.DROPDOWN_MENU
    },
      mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.HYBRID
    }    
    map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map_canvas"), myOptions);
    var infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow();      

    for(i=0; i<GPS.length; i++)
    {     
    //GeoCoding
      if (geocoder) {
      geocoder.geocode({'latLng': latlng}, function(results, status) 
      {
      if (status == google.maps.GeocoderStatus.OK) {
      if (results[1]) {                     
          markers[i] = new google.maps.Marker(
          { 
          position: GPS[i].GPS,
          map: map,
          draggable:true,    
          Info:  results[1].formatted_address,
          title:GPS[i].TITLE
           }
           }
           }
           });    
            google.maps.event.addListener(markers[i], 'click', function() {
            infowindow.setContent(this.Info);
            infowindow.open(map,this);
            });             

         }    
      }


</script>
```

Sir This Is My Updated Code Where I have wrote the Code for Reverse Geocoding But Now MU map Is not Working Please tell me WHAT Exactly I am Missing

Comment: It's easier to debug if it's on a live site or if you put your full code into something like jsFiddle so we can test it out.

Comment: Agree with Mano, you really need to link to live code.

Answer (score 0):

You have commented out geocoder, so it is never is true in you if statement. You have also commented out the call to codeLatLng.

try uncommenting them, for starters!

**UPDATE:**

You dont have elements with the ids you expect in your infobox, where are address and message ?

```
Info: '<table frame=box><tr>
<td align="Left">
<font face="Arial" size=2 color=#336699>Name:</td>
<td align="Left"><font face="Arial" size=2>'+ GPS[i].TITLE + '</font></td></tr><tr>'+
</td><td align="Left"><font face="Arial" size=2>'+ GPS[i].CNT_TEH + '</font></td></tr>'+
              '</table>'
```

This is truly nasty html.. but make sure you have `<span id='address'></span>` or a div also one for message.

Also what does <%= GPS %> render to? dose it need to be quoted?

Comment: Brother thats not Issue I Already tried to uncomment then But All In vain Please Now Tell me how can I display the Geocoder variable on my Infowindow

Comment: I Don't Have element address or message I wan to directly display the Geocoder on My Infowindow on the marker against the correspondent coordinates.Please Tell me HOw can i do this by using geocoder function on infowindow.And Also <%= GPS %> is mY server side variable which is getting all information from Database to make markers and also Infowindow Contents

Comment: @user1103342 what does GPS look like after your server had rendered it? Are you using rails? And where did you get this code? if you want to update the content of your infowindow the code needs to update an element on the page, you are currently telling it to update an element that does not exist as far as i can see from what you have pasted. I understand you dont those elements, what i am telling you is that that is the problem

Comment: Sir Now Please See My Update and also see after Commented Portion for Geocidng code but now may map is not working